# Subtract columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018
Brad,100,200,342,532,65
Tom,54,2,523,121,200
Uma,200,221,225,229,250
```

What I am trying to do is to subtract each year from previous column to this:

```
Name,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018
Brad,0,100,142,190,-467
```

I want to do it automatically and not like this:

```
(df$"2003" - df$"2002")
```

How would it be possible? I'm new to R, I'm sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like

```
# this is your data
df <- data.frame("2014"=c(100,54,200),
             "2015"=c(200,2,221),
             "2016"=c(342,523,225),
             "2017"=c(532,121,229),
             "2018"=c(65,200,250),
             row.names=c("Brad","Tom","Uma"))

df     
#      X2014 X2015 X2016 X2017 X2018
# Brad   100   200   342   532    65
# Tom     54     2   523   121   200
# Uma    200   221   225   229   250
```

...and then you do this

```
df[,-1] - df[,-5]
#      X2015 X2016 X2017 X2018
# Brad   100   142   190  -467
# Tom    -52   521  -402    79
# Uma     21     4     4    21
```

The `df[,-1]` gives every column of your data.frame except the first one, and the `df[,-5]` gives every column except the fifth... from there, it's simple subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(list(X2014 = c(100, 54, 200), X2015 = c(200, 2, 221
), X2016 = c(342, 523, 225), X2017 = c(532, 121, 229), X2018 = c(65, 
200, 250)), .Names = c("X2014", "X2015", "X2016", "X2017", "X2018"
), row.names = c("Brad", "Tom", "Uma"), class = "data.frame")
```

### Solution 1

Since the values for 2014 are all zeros anyway, you can just remove the whole column altogether.

```
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, diff)))
```

### Solution 2

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(t(df)) %>% mutate_all(function(x) x - lag(x,default =x[1]))
df <- data.frame(t(df))
```